# Vue Router: add working history item without invoking push

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, html5-history

I have a vue page that displays a set of components in a certain order. Loading the page with the order will display those elements in order, for example:

```
https://mysite/dashboard/e3e1e2
```

will display components in order of 3,1,2 and

```
https://mysite/dashboard/e1e2e3
```

will display components in order of 1,2,3 etc.

If I change the order of the components in-page, for example by dragging them in a different order, I want to update my url so that it reflects the new order. There are two ways I can accomplish this:

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/dashboard/e3e2e1' }) // or this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard', params: { elOrder: 'e3e2e1' } })
```

or

```
history.pushState({}, null, '/dashboard/e3e2e1'
```

For updating the URL, both work equally well. But here is the problem:

If I use `this.$router.push` my components are reloaded with all their data, when the only thing that has changed about them is their position on the page. However back and forward (history) works as expected.

If I use the `history.pushState` method, I can share that URL and it will load in the correct order for others, and the URL reflects the order on the page while viewing it, but forward navigation is broken (when I go back in history, the forward button will always be greyed out)

What I would like to accomplish is have a working history navigation without unnecessarily reloading all the components whose data has not changed in any way.

Comment: Vue does not reload a component if only the `params` of the route have changed - quite the opposite. You're probably reloading/recreating the components yourself because you're not listening for the `beforeRouteUpdate` hook.

Comment: Thanks! It seems you were correct, I was triggering a reload based on a separate prop I was watching. Once I modified that watcher, it no longer reloads everything.